# Instance Rotation over Lifetime

Tags: animation, particles, instances

I want to have instances rotate randomly over time, seems an easy thing to code, how about it?

I'm trying to make a sparkly / glittery surface to render and wrap around a human face model, or maybe just have instances of glitter rotate on the surface of that model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use modifiers for it in the graph editor tab.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/modifiers.html[image]

Comment: Hi I've just seen this - you answered less than an hour after I asked but the forum never told me! Many thanks :o)